# How to plot a graphic with solution of some inequality?

Tags: plotting, inequalities

I defined the function $z(n)$ by

```
z[n_] := Catch[Do[i; If[Mod[Fibonacci[i], n] == 0, Throw[i]], {i, 100000}]]
```

and now, I would like to plot the graphic (n,z(n)) for points such that $z(n)/n<\epsilon$, for some given value of $\epsilon>0$. For instance, for $\epsilon=0.05$, I used the command

```
Catch[Do[n; If[z[n] < 0.05*n, Print[n]], {n,1, 3000}]]
```

which provides me many values of $n$, but I do not know how to make a graphic with them (they appear in some collumn). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
nn = Table[  If[z[n] < 0.05*n, n, Nothing], {n, 1,3000}] ;
ListPlot[Table[{n, z[n] }, {n, nn}]]
```

[image: 822222]

Alternatively `DiscretePlot` and `RegionFunction` works:

```
DiscretePlot[z[n], {n, 1, 3000},RegionFunction -> Function[{n, z}, z < .05 n ],PlotRange -> {0, 120}, AxesLabel -> {"n", "z[n]"} ]
```

[image]

Don't know where the shadows come from…
88